# elasticsearch model update to 7.0 breaks tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

After updating elasticsearch-model and elastisearch-rails gems to 7.0 causes existing tests to fail.

example test

```
    context 'conditional indexes' do
      it 'a new record should be indexed' do
        new_dept = FactoryBot.create :department
        Department.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
        sleep 2 # let the callbacks work
        # clean query usually done in controller
        query = new_dept.name.gsub(%r{\{|\}|\[|\]|\\|\/|\^|\~|\:|\!|\"|\'}, '')
        expect(Department.search(query).records.count).to eq 1
      end
```

The above test worked correctly until the update now we are seeing this type of error on our elasticsearch tests.

```
     Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::InternalServerError:
       [500] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.lang.String and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"}],"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.lang.String and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"},"status":500}
```

department model

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  # validation
  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { within: 5..50 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_many :faculties, -> { order(:last_name, :first_name) }

  # active status
  enum status: %i[enabled disabled]

  # search
  include Searchable

  # scopes
  scope :visible, -> { where(status: 'enabled') }
  scope :order_name, -> { order(:name) }

  # Elastic Search Index settings.
  # These are set in the model to index only specific information.   
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :name, type: :text
    end
  end

  # Elastic Search Settings
  # @description
  # indexed json, this will help with search rankings.
  # rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Department' SCOPE="visible" FORCE=y
  def as_indexed_json(_options)
    as_json(
      only: %i[id name],
      include: {
        faculties: { only: :name }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Testing in rails console

```
systems = Department.create(name: "Test Department");
systems.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
```

Return the following

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_index!' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Proxy::InstanceMethodsProxy:0x00007f12301ddf28>
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-model-7.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/model/proxy.rb:121:in `method_missing'
```

Any help would be appreciated.
If anyone needs to see the full project it is available on github at https://github.com/wvulibraries/TLC-Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading my elasticsearch docker container to 7.5.0 corrected the issue I was seeing.